# pyspark json datframe created with all null values

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I have created a dataframe from a json file. However dataframe is created with all the schema but with values as null. Its a valid json file.

`df = spark.read.json(path)`

when I displayed the data , using `df.display()` all i can view is null in the dataframe. Can anyone tell me what could be the issue?

Comment: Please provide sample input data to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Its a huge file... not able to share it here

Comment: Tried creating RDD and then create dataframe using it, However there is some error.It says there is relative path in absolute URI.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the json file without **enabling multiline** might be the cause for this.

Please go through the sample demonstration.

My sample json.

```
[{"id":1,"first_name":"Amara","last_name":"Taplin"},
{"id":2,"first_name":"Gothart","last_name":"McGrill"},
{"id":3,"first_name":"Georgia","last_name":"De Miranda"},
{"id":4,"first_name":"Dukie","last_name":"Arnaud"},
{"id":5,"first_name":"Mellicent","last_name":"Scathard"}]
```

I got null values when multiline not used.

[image]

When multiline enabled I got proper result.

```
df= spark.read.option('multiline', True).json('/FileStore/tables/Sample1_json.json')
df.display()
```

[image]

If you want to give schema externally also, you can do like this.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType,LongType

schema = StructType([StructField('first_name', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('id', IntegerType(), True),
                     StructField('last_name', StringType(), True)])
                    
df= spark.read.schema(schema).option('multiline', True).json('/FileStore/tables/Sample1_json.json')
df.show()
```